# How to remove white margins from ePub in Google Play Books

Tags: epub, google-play-books

Google Play Books seems to put a default white margin in every ePub being reading. But this is bad for making responsive covers in the first page.

Even with margin set to zero in both html and body tags, the Google Play Books adds an extra margin to the page. I was able to overcome this problem with hacks using negative margins, absolute postition and so on, but this can mess the view with others ebook readers.

Is there a way to make hacks specific for Google Play Books in similar way that is webpages hacks for browsers? I couldn't find any documentation about it in Google Developers or IDPF.org.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28application%29) to change the margins and border by changing the style file. 
If you have many files to change, you might be better of using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)'s EPUB to EPUB conversion and setting the margins for the output file to your liking.

If you don't have access to these tools and know about CSS, you can also unzip the EPUB files, change the style sheet by hand and rezip the files back into an EPUB. (This sounds more complicated than it is.)

Comment: I prefer the unzip and CSS way myself. +1

Comment: @Anthon, I tried to edit the CSS, but the problem is that even with margin set to zero in both html and body tags, the Google Play Books adds an extra margin to the page. I was able to overcome this problem with hacks using negative margins, absolute postition and so on, but this can messing the view with others ebook readers. Is there a way to make hacks specific for Google Play Books in similar way that is webpages hacks for browsers? I couldn't find any documentation about it in Google Developers or IDPF.org.

Comment: @user2067157 I just got me a Google Play Book to anaylyse. Is there a specific device/software you are viewing this on? Any particular title. BTW it is best to add extended specific information to the question, so others don't have to wade through the comments to understand specifics of the Q (and As). Just leave a short comment (or a message in chat if you have the rep) in case I don't notice the update.

Comment: @user2067157 None of the 3 files I have from google play have excessive margins. I cannot really reproduce the problem without further info.

Comment: @Anthon, to reproduce the problem just try to put a green background in any page of an ePub using the html tag. You will se that a small white margin exist. If you have a epub with a jpg you can see that the picture can't take all the screen space.